# Git errors for a repo on network drive

Tags: git, github, network-drive

I've created a network drive for my locally hosted website, and I'm managing all my files directly on the network drive. And I'm using that network drive as a local git repo. So, if I make any changes to a file there, I'd also want to be able to push it my my remote git repo. But when I start to do that, its gives me so many errors. Sometimes, it fails to check the status, sometimes gives errors such as

1. "fatal: index file smaller than expected"
2. "fatal: Unable to create 'Y:/demo.dotcms.com/demos/tstgit/.git/index.lock': File exists."
3. "error: update_ref failed for ref 'HEAD': cannot lock ref 'HEAD': Unable to create 'Y:/demo.dotcms.com/demos/tstgit/.git/refs/heads/master.lock': File exists."
4. "error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': Unable to create Y:/demo.dotcms.com/demos/tstgit/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock': File exists."

I've googled and followed every direction I could in:
1. http://codybonney.com/fixing-fatal-index-file-smaller-than-expected-error/
2. http://programertools.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-fix-fatal-index-file-smaller.html
 and a few others

But I'm still getting these issues.
However, when I try to check status, stage, commit, push, everything seems to work fine when I do it from my local drive. It also works when I map a network drive to a shared drive. But I get these errors only when working on a network drive mapped to my locally hosted site.
Please help.

Comment: Just to clarify, does your network drive have different directories for what you're treating as the git remote and the `.git` directory under the working tree on the network, or is it the same directory?

Comment: The network drive has different directories.
Like Y:/abc, Y:/xyz, Y:/demos

My git remote is the enterprise git of my project.

My working directory is one of those directories, Y:/demos/ecgittest which has the .git directory in it.